# How to block a part of the level plot in R made using lattice package?

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I have made a level plot in R of a variable using the lattice package. This grid corresponds to South Asia. I am only interested in viewing the values of this variable (aerosol optical depth) for certain countries in South Asia. I have a dummy variable that takes the value 1 for the countries I am interested in and 0 otherwise. Is it possible for me to colour this part of the grid black or any other colour?

I cannot show the level plot as I am low on reputation with stackoverflow. (The pdf that was attached to the crossposted message to rhelp should now appear:)

Here is my R code:

```
levelplot(aod ~ longitude + latitude | factor(day), data = aod_Jan, 
    aspect="iso", contour = TRUE, layout=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using geographical data, maybe the `raster` package is useful for you. For example, let's display the altitude of France (download this [`zip`](http://diva-gis.org/data/alt/FRA_alt.zip) file or use the `raster::getData` function). After you `unzip` the file:

```
library(raster)
fraAlt <- raster('FRA_alt')
plot(fraAlt) ## Not only France is displayed...
```

If you want to display only the altitude of France, you need the information of the boundaries: download this [`RData`](http://gadm.org/data/rda/FRA_adm0.RData) file (or use the `raster::getData` function). This `RData` contains a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` (named `gadm`) which can be converted to a `Raster` with:

```
 mk <- rasterize(gadm, fraAlt)
```

Now you can mask the altitude raster with the boundaries:

```
 fraAltMask <- mask(fraAlt, x)
 plot(fraAltMask) ##Now only France is displayed
```

Finally, if you want to use `lattice` methods you need the `rasterVis` package:

```
 library(rasterVis)
 levelplot(fraAlt)
 levelplot(fraAltMask)
```

Now, all together with the boundaries superimposed:

```
 s <- stack(fraAlt, fraAltMask)
 layerNames(s) <- c('Alt', 'AltMask')
 boundaries <- as(gadm, 'SpatialLines')
 levelplot(s) + layer(sp.lines(boundaries))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Oscar! I haven't tried it out yet. But will do so over the weekend. But I wanted to thank you for your response. Will let you know if it works.

Comment: Oscar the nature of my problem now stands changed. I want to be able to identify the states of India on that map. For this purpose I have a shapefile of the states of India. But I don't know how to proceed in this direction any further. I want to be able to overlay the boundaries of the states of Indian fiven by the shapefile onto this levelplot. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: @Ridhima You can read a shapefile with `maptools::readShapeLines`. The result can be overlaid with `layer(sp.lines(object))`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the subset argument to levelplot. Perhaps:

```
levelplot(aod ~ longitude + latitude | factor(day), data = aod_Jan, subset = dummy==1,
    aspect="iso", contour = TRUE, layout=c(1,1))
```

Comment: David the above was not a solution to the problem hence the query was posted on R help. I got an error saying the no proper Z matrix specified.

Comment: Although conditioning on this dummy worked. I just have to figure out how to get rid of the graphs where the dummy equals 0 .

Comment: Without a more complete description of the data, anything would be utter guesswork. Experimentation with the example in levelplot shows that subset works, and that the x and y ranges are properly contracted when subsetting. As long as you are offering no code and data, the source of your errors will remain obscure.